# KQL conditional sub query

Tags: azure, monitor, azure-data-explorer, kql

Hello my friends on the internet,
I want to show rows in condition that they not appear in other ways on other rows.
For example I have this table:

| Name | LastName | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abby | Abbson | OK |
| Abby | Abbson | Not OK |
| Bobby | Bobson | Not OK |
| Sandra | Mayer | OK |

I want to show all the people in Status 'Not OK' as long as they don't have also a record with 'OK' status, so for my example the result will be only:

| Name | LastName | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bobby | Bobson | Not OK |

I'm lost already if someone can please give me a guideline for this it will be great, thanks!

Comment: What if a person has no `OK` record, but has multiple `Not OK` records? Do you want to see one record of this person or multiple records? Do you have other fields you want to see in the result or only `Name`+`LastName`? Is that really your unique identifier of a person?

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, you just need to verify that there are no `OK` records for a person.

```
datatable(Name:string,LastName:string,Status:string)
[
     "Abby"  ,"Abbson" ,"OK"
    ,"Abby"  ,"Abbson" ,"Not OK"
    ,"Bobby" ,"Bobson" ,"Not OK"
    ,"Sandra","Mayer"  ,"OK"
]
| summarize countif(Status == "OK") by Name, LastName
| where countif_ == 0
```

| Name | LastName | countif_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bobby | Bobson | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/demo12.westus/databases/GitHub?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUDb/E3FSr4pKizLx0HZ/E4hJkfjBQUWkxlKfJyxXNy6UAAkqOSUmVSgoKOiBGcX6eEpDl760EkdXBJuuXX6KApMIpH6wEzMCuIjgxL6UoUUlHyTexMrUIbBpYNpaXq0ahuDQ3N7EosypVITm/NK8kM00D4lIFW1sFkDJNhaRKBZBHdBRgXgJpK89ILYJriQcpNgAAZ2XGiQgBAAA=)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
datatable (Name: string, LastName: string, Status: string) [
    "Abby","Abbson","OK",
    "Abby","Abbson","Not OK",
    "Bobby","Bobson","Not OK",
    "Sandra","Mayer","OK"
]
| summarize make_set(Status) by Name, LastName
| where array_index_of( set_Status,"Not OK") >= 0 and array_length( set_Status) == 1
```

| Name | LastName | set_Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bobby | Bobson | [ "Not OK" ] |